# MVC reading from a dynamic list of SQL tables

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have an application that is using MVC framework that currently reads from a model object of a SQL table and puts the results in a list format. The table has its own .cs class with all the necessary fields and the code filters the results based on other factors.

The problem I am running into, is that I need to find a way to add new tables to this list without making changes to the code itself. Ideally, I would like to add a list of tables I need to read from into the web.config and create a class for them in the project structure and the code will dynamically read from that.

Currently with one table the code looks like this:

```
 var assets = _model.FMIF.ToList();
 var results = BuildFormatedResult(assets);
```

And I have been able to add another table to this structure like this:

```
    var assets = _model.FMIF.ToList();
    var assets2 = _model.FMHZ.ToList();
    assets = assets.Concat(assets2).ToList();
    var results = BuildFormatedResult(assets);
```

I have tried to make this dynamic using a method like this:

```
    var test = "FMIF";
    var assets = _model.+test+.ToList();
    var results = BuildFormatedResult(assets);
```

but it does not appear to be able to read the variable as a model.

Is there a best practice way to do something like this? Even if it is way different than what I have tried I am kind of at a loss here. Not super familiar with MVC structure so any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Read up on Reflection.  See also [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=net-5.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an approach I've used to dynamically get a handle to a DbSet. Firstly I define a couple of methods (This does assume that you have the classes already generated for each of the tables.)

```
    public static DbSet GetDbSet(MyDbContext db, string tableName)
    {
        // Find the EF entity that corresponds to this table
        ObjectContext objectContext = (db as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
        var mappings = GetEntityMappings(objectContext);
        var entityName = mappings[tableName];

        // Now get the corresponding DbSet
        DbSet dbSet = (DbSet)db.Set(Type.GetType("schema_name." + entityName));
        return dbSet;
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, string> GetEntityMappings(ObjectContext objectContext)
    {
        var EntityMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        // Build a list of database table names to EF entity names
        // Get a list of entities
        MetadataWorkspace workspace = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
        var entities = workspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.CSpace);

        foreach (EntityType et in entities)
        {
            // Get the entity set that uses this entity type
            var entitySet = workspace
                            .GetItems<EntityContainer>(DataSpace.CSpace)
                            .Single()
                            .EntitySets
                            .Single(s => s.ElementType.Name == et.Name);
            // Find the mapping between conceptual and storage model for this entity set
            var mapping = workspace.GetItems<EntityContainerMapping>(DataSpace.CSSpace)
                            .Single()
                            .EntitySetMappings
                            .Single(s => s.EntitySet == entitySet);
            // Find the storage entity set (table) that the entity is mapped to
            var table = mapping
                            .EntityTypeMappings.Single()
                            .Fragments.Single()
                            .StoreEntitySet;

            string tableName = (string)table.MetadataProperties["Table"].Value ?? table.Name;

            EntityMappings.Add(tableName, et.Name);
        }

        return EntityMappings;
    }
```

Basically it is poking around in the EntityFramework metadata in order to map a string of a table name to the entity name (which aren't necessarily the same). This is slightly simplified as ideally you would cache the mappings.

Then finally call the GetDbSet() method, I've used AsQueryable() as I potentially need to add where clauses etc.

```
    var dbSet = GetDbSet(db, "table_name").AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Thank you - going to try this out and I will let you know. Really appreciate it.